# Static TableView Cells not showing in iOS9 until scrolled back into view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

When testing my app on `iOS9`, I have some Static TableViewCells that show up completely blank, but show normal in `iOS8`.

If I scroll those cells outside of the view and then back, the content magically appears.

This is an `iPhone only` app, so I am using `wCompact hRegular`:

[image]

Have a feeling it has to do with Size Classes and Autolayout.

Using XCode 7 Beta 5.

Anyone seen this happen?

Comment: Me too facing same issue, if you had solution please share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unchecking "Use Size Classes" option and then coming back and re-checking it again fixes this issue.

- In the project navigator, select a storyboard or xib file.
- The file’s contents open in Interface Builder.
- Choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector.
- In the Interface Builder Document section, un-tick the "Use Size Classes" checkbox.
- Leave the menu. Come back and tick
  the "Use Size Classes" checkbox again.

Credit goes to [`Max108` on the Apple Dev Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/40303#41782).

Comment: Thanks dude.. this answer Saved  my day !!